# How to make tables with horizontal lines with csvautotabular of csvsimple?

Tags: csvsimple

How do you make tables with horizontal lines between rows with the `csvautotabular` function of the `csvsimple` package?

Example .csv file.

```
header,
104, 1
312, 0.223
518, 0.198
726, 0.139
932, 0.077
```

Comment: Can you add an example of code?

Comment: As in to call `csvautotabular`? There is nothing but `\csvautotabular{xxx.csv}`.

Comment: With a sample from `xxx.csv`

Comment: Multiple row, multiple column numerical data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\csvautotabular` macro is intended for a quick tabular overview. It is quite simple and is not really suitable for customization.

In my example code, I offer a hack solution `my hack` to provide the requested feature. But for productive code, I would rather use a customizable solution with `\csvreader` or `\csvloop`. I also added several examples for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{example.csv}
header,
104, 1
312, 0.223
518, 0.198
726, 0.139
932, 0.077
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\csvset{
  my hack/.style={
    late after line=\\\hline,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hacked autotabular:\par\smallskip
\csvautotabular[my hack]{example.csv}

\medskip

Better with csvreader and tabular:\par\smallskip
\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|,
  table head=\hline header & \\\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline]%
  {example.csv}{}%
{\csvlinetotablerow}%

\medskip

Alternatively:\par\smallskip
\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|,
  no head,
  table head=\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline]%
  {example.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%

\medskip

Alternatively:\par\smallskip
\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|,
  no head,column count=2,
  table head=\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline]%
  {example.csv}{}%
{\csvlinetotablerow}%

\medskip

Alternatively:\par\smallskip
\csvloop{
  file=example.csv,
  no head,column count=2,
  tabular=|l|l|,
  table head=\hline,
  command=\csvlinetotablerow,
  late after line=\\\hline
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `\csvlinetotablerow` do under `\csvreader` please?

Comment: `\csvlinetotablerow` typesets the current processed data line with `&` between the entries. Here, this means `\csvcoli & \csvcolii`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular[respect sharp]{mycsv.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image: csvtbl]

Comment: there is no horizontal lines between data entries though?